# Print the callstack of debugger (method names) to the file or console in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, logging

Is it possible to print route of debugger into the file or console? I think about e.g names of methods where it actually enter. 
In other words what I see hit F11, F11, F11 ... I want to have in file.
How can I do this?

Comment: This is a built-in feature for the VS2010 Ultimate edition called IntelliTrace.  I'm going to guess you don't have that edition, you may have to make do with the Debug + Windows + Call Stack window.

Comment: @Hans Passant - does IntelliTrace support x64 projects? Call Stack show me where I am in current moment. I'd like to have this trace in some txt file. Any simple method to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could add the following to your code, or just run it from the [Immediate Window](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx&ei=US9xTrPbG8r3sgbN39CCBw&usg=AFQjCNH3P7_tPLvWwKB9Wjnzbx59rU2WUg) when you are in Break mode:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("myTrace.txt", new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).ToString())
```

Alternatively, you could add [tracepoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39594261/1465553) to your code and use the $CALLSTACK psuedo-variable.

**UPDATE:** I'm a co-creator of a Visual Studio extensions called [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com), and I added a [feature](http://www.oz-code.com/features/#trace) that makes it much easier to do what OP requested. The feature is essentially "Tracepoints on Steroids".

To do this, use the QuickAction "Create Tracepoint Here"

[image: Create Tracepoint]

Then, enter some text and/or expressions you want to appear next to the callstack, and make sure "Save Stack" is checked:

[image: Save Stack]

Then, every time you hit your tracepoint, a new line will be added to the Tracepoint Viewer. You can view the full callstack by clicking the arrow next to it:

[image: Export]

Now, just hit the "Export" button in the top-right corner to save all your callstacks to a file.