# What is the meaning of the square/diamond breakpoint in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I placed 2 breakpoints and one of them turned square. What does it mean? If it helps I am remotely debugging some code.

[image: screenshot of the breakpoints window]

Comment: It is conditional breakpoint. You can specify some condition like someValue == true then only then it will hit.

Comment: @fhnaseer No, the indication for that is having a plus sign in the breakpoint symbol.

Comment: "◇" is a diamond (or less commonly, rhombus), "□" is a square. While I rarely ever post comments of this nature, I think it's important to note because people are more likely to be searching for the correct term for the symbol when encountering this situation.

Comment: It is indeed referred to as a diamond in the documentation which is actually why I did not catch it in my search through the debugging section. It looks like it has 4 right angles which makes it a square still regardless of rotation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means execution will not break at that breakpoint, but only a message will be output in the debugging log.

To change this, right click on the breakpoint and choose "Settings" (In older VS Version) or "Actions" (starting with VS 2017).

[image]

See this question for why this is useful:

- [What are tracepoints used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066756/what-are-tracepoints-used-for)

Answer (score 5):

square breakpoint you mention is **Breakpoint actions and tracepoints**.

According to [learn.microsoft.com debugger using breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017#BKMK_Print_to_the_Output_window_with_tracepoints)

> A tracepoint is a breakpoint that prints a message to the Output window. A tracepoint can act like a temporary trace statement in the programming language.

You can change the breakpoint setting by click on setting button near breakpoint by moving cursor to breakpoint.